# Jump value don't add. it keep the same value

Tags: c#, godot

ok so I'm coding a game and I need a double jump right. Problem the value does not change

(ther is more information at the end of the post conserning the code.

here is the code

```
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class CharacterBody2D : Godot.CharacterBody2D
{
    public const float Speed = 300.0f;
    public const float JumpVelocity = -400.0f;
    int jumpmax = 0;

    // Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
    public float gravity = ProjectSettings.GetSetting("physics/2d/default_gravity").AsSingle();

    public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta)
    {
        Vector2 velocity = Velocity;
    

        // Add the gravity.
        if (!IsOnFloor())
        {
            velocity.Y += gravity * (float)delta;
            jumpmax = 0;
         }
        // Handle Jump.
        
        
            if (Input.IsActionJustPressed("ui_accept") & jumpmax < 2 )
            {
                        jumpmax = jumpmax + 1;
                    velocity.Y = JumpVelocity;
                    GD.Print(jumpmax);
             }      
        
        
         
       
        // Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
        // As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
        Vector2 direction = Input.GetVector("ui_left", "ui_right", "ui_up", "ui_down");
        if (direction != Vector2.Zero)
        {
            velocity.X = direction.X * Speed;
        }
        else
        {
            velocity.X = Mathf.MoveToward(Velocity.X, 0, Speed);
        }

        Velocity = velocity;
        MoveAndSlide();
    }
}`
```

i was expecting the jump max value to go up but it keep getting a 1 value in the command prompt. unfortunetly even after countless try and change in the code i still got no progress in the code for the double jump. right now the code make it jump as much as you like and i want it to get a limit of 2 jump if this is possible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaTHF.png)`your text

Comment: I assume that if `if (Input.IsActionJustPressed("ui_accept") & jumpmax < 2 )` is true then the next frame `IsOnFloor()` will be false and reset `jumpmax` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here you reset the jump counter when the character is NOT on the floor:

```
if (!IsOnFloor())
{
    velocity.Y += gravity * (float)delta;
    jumpmax = 0;
}
```

You want to reset the jump counter when the character is on the floor:

```
if (IsOnFloor())
{
    jumpmax = 0;
}
else
{
    velocity.Y += gravity * (float)delta;
}
```